# Sync iOS Core Data with WCF + SQL Server

Tags: ios, sql-server, wcf, core-data, synchronization

How can we sync the iOS Core Data with the SQL Database as per user?

We are using WCF as a Services and SQL Server as a database..?

Is there any way to Sync Inserted/Updated/Delete data only with iOS Core Data with SQL Server data?

Any input would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do it by writing your own custom sync code.

Core Data will let you know what has changed locally by posting `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`. From that you can work out which objects have been created/updated/deleted on the iOS device.

Sending those changes to the server is your job.

Comment: We have some different case. We are first changes on Server Side and then All App Clients will request do data to the server.. and we only want to save the new inserted/updated/deleted data to the server into iOS Core Data